# Golang: consume items for multiple workers from channel in `case` statement

Tags: go

My consumer (run from `main`) supports context cancellation and reading from a channel via `case` statement. I can shutdown the consumer with the context, that works fine. However, when I spawn several workers in one case statement, every worker is given the same job (message) from `jobsChan`, which is not what I want:

```golang
func (app *App) consumer() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-app.ctx.Done():
            app.infoLog.Print("Caught SIGINT, stopping.")
            app.wg.Wait()
            app.doneChan <- struct{}{} # main uses this channel to block itself until all goroutines are stopped
            app.infoLog.Print("Shutting down the consumer...")
            return
        case job := <-app.jobsChan:
            // PROBLEM here: wrong, each worker is given the same job
            for workerNumber := 0; workerNumber < app.config.workers; workerNumber++ {
                app.wg.Add(1)
                go app.workerFunc(workerNumber, job)
            }
        }
    }
}

func (app *App) workerFunc(id int, job Job) {
    defer app.wg.Done()
    
    ... actual worker code here ...
}
```

How can I rewrite this code so that I can keep `select` for `app.ctx.Done` channel and at the same time can spawn workers so that each worker picks next message from the channel as a Job? I need to keep `for/select` to listen for `ctx` cancellation but at the same time I need to spawn X workers reading messages from `jobsChan` in the consumer. Is this possible?

The only alternative that comes to mind is passing channel directly into spawned `workerFunc` and have another `for job := range app.jobsChan` in the `workerFunc`. But then the whole `case job := <-app.jobsChan:` in the consumer becomes pointless and I am not sure how to rewrite it.

To clarify: When I run the app, I expect every worker to have a new job id pulled from the `jobsChan` - but they all process the same, e.g. 1, then they all process the next one, e.g. 2

```
#wrong
Worker 0: start processing item 1
Worker 2: start processing item 1
Worker 1: start processing item 1
```

Comment: Making sure I follow, you want to create a `app.config.workers` number of `app.workerFunc` goroutines for each job you pull off jobsChan?  If you only pull one `job` why spawn more than one goroutine?  Or are you trying to use a fixed number of `workers` to process jobs?  An example demonstrating your problem can help.

Comment: yes @sberry, I have tens of items in my channel I want to process in several concurrently running goroutines. In my current setup I cannot do it as all goroutines are given the same job. I was following the tutorial here https://www.rodrigoaraujo.me/posts/golang-pattern-graceful-shutdown-of-concurrent-events/

Comment: If you remove the `for` loop. Each worker should get a different job, if no job is sent multiple times over the channel. The purpose of the `for` loop is unclear.
Maybe you'd find this package useful: https://github.com/MicahParks/ctxerrpool

Comment: @MicahParks that did not help. Workers are still being invoked with the same jobs. 

Jobs are being added to the queue in the handler. Images are being uploaded via Postman and as soon as image arrives, it is being added to the buffered channel. So I don't see how it would end up in the queue (channel) several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing code explicitly assigns the same job to all the workers. If you have a fixed number of workers, create goroutines for them (during initialization), and have them listen to a channel:

```
for workerNumber:0;workerNumber<app.config.workers;workerNumber++ {
   go app.workerFunc(ctx,workerNumber,app.jobsChan)
}
```

In each worker, simply check the jobQueue and the context cancellation.

In other words, you don't need the `consumer`, pass jobs directly to the workers.

Comment: Thank you @Burak Serdar. This solution worked. I also needed to close channel in `main` when server is finished and I also removed all `for, select, case` statements from the `consumer` to leave only blocking on `<-app.ctx.Done()` and commands after that.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. What I meant was that you don't need a `consumer` function. All you need are the workers and a common channel from which they read.